# What is the best learning to hashing for embedding points in a Vector Space in Hamming Space?

Tags: machine-learning, hamming-distance

I have a cloud of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and I want to embed them in Hamming Space.

One possible solution is for example found in [Inductive Hashing on Manifolds](https://cs.adelaide.edu.au/users/chhshen/projects/inductive_hashing/cvpr13a.pdf).

The problem is:

I need an extremely fast evaluation of a new embedding when a new point arrives in my data (the so called out-of-sample extension problem) but I haven't found any comparison between the existing algorithms supporting out-of-sample extension.

Question: What is the learning to hash algorithm with the **FASTEST** solution for the out-of-sample extension problem?

Notes:

1. The algorithm must be trained in linear time because I am thinking in very large applications.
2. Probably I will not find a learning to hash algorithm with simultaneously high MAP and fast out-of-sample extension time, so tell me the fastest instead of the more accurate.

Comment: You probably have some requirements you haven't stated.  The mapping that maps every point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to the bitvector $00000$ meets all of the requirements stated in the question, but I doubt you'll be satisfied with it.  Perhaps you have some requirements about how the distances in $\mathbb{R}^n$ must be related to the Hamming distances between embeddings.   Please [edit] the question to state all requirements explicitly.

Comment: It is is OBVIOUS the requirement is that the embedding must map near points in euclidean space to near points in Hamming space. Otherless the embedding would be useless for applications like image retrieval, as exemplified in the article.

Comment: The user of stackexchange who has studied or researched in the area "Learning to hash" will understand what I am writing. You don't understand nothing what I need D.W. probably because you haven't studied this area. I have already stated @D.W. you are well intentioned but you don't understand my intentions and write pedestrain commentaries...

Comment: I encourage you to state the exact requirements explicitly.  I can guess there must be some such requirement, but what exactly is it, and how is it formalized, and how strong must it be?  You are asking what the fastest algorithm is that meets (some requirements); to know what exactly is fastest, we must know exactly what the requirements are and just how good the scheme must be.  I encourage you to provide some background and make it useful for others.  If you think answerers will have everything needed to understand how to answer and how to evaluate answers, that is your call.